# How to use React Spring in a HOC?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-spring

I am sure that this is relate to me not totally understanding how React Spring works or maybe HOCs.

I am trying to create a HOC for React that adds a React Spring animation (slides the child component in from the left)

```
const SlideLeft = WrappedComponent => {
  const [props] = useSpring({
    translateX: "0",
    from: { translateX: "1000vw" }
  });
  return (
    <animated.div style={props}>
      <WrappedComponent />
    </animated.div>
  );
};
```

And then later on, in another component, I have this:

```
    <SlideLeft>
      <Categories />
    </SlideLeft>
```

I would think this would work, but instead I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: arr[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
```

I found this page which suggested changing it to just const props:

https://github.com/react-spring/react-spring/issues/616

However, when I do that I get the error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `SlideLeft`.
```

So I'm not quite sure how to get a HOC working with React Spring.

Any information would be illuminating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define wrapper like this:

```
 export function SlideLeft(props) {
      const animationProps = useSpring({
        from: { transform: "translate3d(-100%,0,0)" },
        to: { transform: "translate3d(0%,0,0)" }
      });

      return <animated.div style={{ ...animationProps }}> {props.children} </animated.div>;
    }
```

And call from the parent component like this:

```
  <SlideLeft>
    <yourComponent/>
  </SlideLeft>
```

Note that in the `from` and `to` objects, I am using the same `unit`, namely `percentage`. Using the same unit is important. If you use different unit, or pass unit-less numbers it won't work.

Comment: Can you not use const for this then?

Comment: @CecilRodriguez Const in the function definition? You can, like this: `const  SlideLeft = (props) => { ....`